# Receive procedure values in columns automatically

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table buildings
(
id mediumint auto_increment primary key,
assigned int default 0
);

create table performances
(
id mediumint auto_increment primary key,
);

create table assigned
(
id mediumint auto_increment primary key,
performance int references performances(id),
building int references buildings(id)
);
```

I've just begun learning MySQL.
I'm trying to create a column buildings(assigned) that would receive a certain value.
I want to count assigned(id)s where buildings(id) == assigned(building) and have buildings(assigned) updated automatically every time I add or delete a record in assigned.

Is there a way to do it?
I was guessing procedure but it seems procedures aren't automatic.

---

Thanks to your comments, now I get I should use triggers.
But, if possible, can I get an example showing how it's done?
I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding the document and implementing it.

Comment: You can do it with a trigger.

Comment: [Triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) can be used to do that, but I'd caution that normally you don't need to store the count in the table -- you can use SQL to compute it on the fly!  (There are *some* times when it does make sense to store it, however)

Comment: When you create a foreign key, it automatically indexes it. So `COUNT(*) GROUP BY building` will be efficient. You shouldn't need to store it in the table.